# "after use" or "after using"?

Tags: grammar

Tell me please which sentence is correct.

> Wipe the benches after use!
>
> Wipe the benches after using!

I guess the following ones is correct, but too long.

> Wipe the benches after you use them!
>
> Wipe the benches after using them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's perfectly idiomatic to say:

> Wipe the benches after use

and this is typical of a request that you might find in a park or other public place.

It's also correct, although it takes a moment longer, to say:

> Wipe the benches after you use them
>   Wipe the benches after using them.

This is what a parent might say to a child. It's informal and natural rather than **official speak**.

It's not idiomatic to say **Wipe the benches after using**. It leaves open the question **using what?**

Stick to the concise request form in your first example or the slightly longer constructions in your final examples. There's nothing wrong with taking a little longer. The question is only which one best fits the context.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is correct and the simplest:

> Wipe the benches after use!

You can't just say *after using* but only *after using them,* as in your last example.